# delete contents of nth file in a folder batch

Tags: batch-file, file-io

I have a program that does things with video files depending on the file order, so for example it calls on the 45th or 10th file in a folder, but never the same one twice. Now, to save SSD space I want to delete only the contents of that nth file while keeping the file itself.

Comment: The nth by what sorting? Alphabetical? Chronological?

Comment: Alphabetical order. This is the standard, so I didn't think I needed to clarify.

Comment: You said "depending on the file order" - I read that meaning you work with more than one ordering. Anyway, if you are willing to use PowerShell, it becomes trivial - `"" > (gci)[45]`  - gci lists the files and folders as an array, echo an empty string into the file named in position 45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A batch file solution isn't much fun, because batch can't really count or deal with arrays and indexes, it needs to work like: setup a counter, list the files, count through them, when the count matches the number you want, do something.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set i=0

for %%f in (*) do (
  set /A i=!i!+1
  if !i! EQU 45 (
    echo overwriting %%f
    rem echo. > %%f 
  )    
)
```

`rem` makes the line a comment (remark), remove `rem` to make it actually overwrite files.

NB that this doesn't handle subdirectories gracefully.